# Finding E(Y) (conditional probability with Poisson distribution)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose that X has a Poisson distribution with the rate $\lambda$ and suppose the conditional distribution of Y, given$ X=x$, is binomial with parameters x and p.

Find E(Y).
The law of total expectation is \begin{align} &E(Y)= E(E(Y|X)) \\ =&E(Xp)\\=& p E(X) \end{align}

> Question: Can someone justify the problem solving process please?

Comment: Which step are you confused about?

Comment: @angryavian Mainly, how we interpret Poisson distribution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the law of total probability, for any nonegative integer $k$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y=k) &= \sum_{n=k}^\infty \mathbb P(Y=k\mid X=n)\mathbb P(X=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda p}\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!},
\end{align}
so that $Y\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda p)$. It follows immediately that $\mathbb E[Y] = \lambda p$.